# Cox PH model on 3 groups of same subjects but under varying conditions to see how it affects the survival - should I use clustering?

Tags: repeated-measures, survival, cox-model, kaplan-meier, clustered-standard-errors

There's a group of subjects. They experience events depending on (defined by) certain conditions. I was asked by a researcher to perform a sensitivity analysis on 3 different ways to define the conditions, to see how the survival curves will change.

I want to use the Cox model, to get the HRs (the PHs hold well in my example and agree with theoretical considerations).

I'm in doubt. The Cox model requires independence of observations. Here we have 3 sets of the same subjects, just with partially different distribution of events - some of the events occur at the same moment, some timepoints are changed by the varying conditions.

This causes a pseudo-replication and resembles clustering in multi-level (mixed or GEE) models (where each subject creates a cluster). I use R, so I could use the +cluster(ID) in my model to handle this and calculate robust standard errors, taking care of the fact, that - even if the distributions of events partially differ across the curves, then still some within-subject correlation may still occur.

The problem is, that when I treat the 3 groups as independent, the significant difference is only between 2 pairs of them (C-A and B-A, which doesn't surprise, they are far from each other). And this is what suggests the KM estimate (which of course "doesn't know" about any dependence, just takes data as they are). When I adjust for the clustering in Cox, now all 3 curves are mutually statistically different (including C vs. B). **That's OK,** it doesn't surprises me, being a textbook example of how the "dependency" matters in testing and can "catch more".

**What bothers me** is - should I treat them as dependent or independent anyway? In real scenarios, the groups will be different. It's just this trial, where I have the same group assessed under 3 different conditions...

I cannot publish 2 contradictory results, for sure. I don't catch for stat. significance, I don't care, I'm rather wondering which approach is appropriate.

I know this analysis is tricky, but it's just an exploratory approach. I have no other way to compare the hazards coming from different settings. Cox gives me the PHs and I like it.

So, let's skip potential "it doesn't make much sense", which won't help me, and let's think how to handle this issue, what's your arguments for treating the 3 groups as dependent (because it's about **same group in 3 conditions ONLY in THIS** trial) vs. independent (because normally it won't be the same group).

Maybe just pretend I don't know it's the same group and treat them independently?

[image]

Comment: The minimal number of subjects to estimate an entire survival curve is in the 190 range if most of them have events.  Look at the Cox regression chapter of the [RMS course notes](https://hbiostat.org/rms).

Comment: Thank you, but I ask about either using clustering or not in this approach. I cannot get anything more, have to complete the analysis. BTW I never required more especially with a single covariate to get satisfying results. Most of them are events (48).

Comment: You missed my point.  If your sample size is too small to do the most simple thing it's almost surely too small to do something more difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Do you have some suggestions about the problem in question? Let's forget the sample size. I will remove it from the text. Just made a few simulations, and at my sample size and number of events, the method properly catches my intentions in both cases. The issue is about the way of thinking on the 3 groups.

Comment: What do you mean when you say: "They experience events depending on (defined by) certain conditions"? Does the definition of an "event" differ in the 3 scenarios? Or is an "event" the same thing in each scenario, but the covariates (conditions) used to model the events differ among scenarios? That's not clear to me from the question, and an answer would differ depending on that distinction.